# Tera term - Apply macro to multiple open windows (connections)

Tags: macros, serial-port

I am using Tera term to control multiple serial channels (6).
I am connected to all of them at the same time.
I would like to apply the macro at the same time on all the windows.

I have been looking around but not been able to find a solution.

I wrote a batch file that call teramacro.exe and connect to each port. But the macro is done one port at the time while I would like to see it synchronously. If I cut my script in single actions, the batch file then try to open a new window (unsuccessful since a previous one is already connected).

Regards,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your batch and it works
start ttermpro.exe /F=config1.ini
start ttermpro.exe /F=config2.ini

Answer (score 0):

you can open multiple teraterm windows. All the opened windows are shown as tabs below the window (just like task manager in windows OS)